# Dynamic FLOT legend table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flot, legend

I have a somewhat limited knowledge of JS and JQuery so I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I have a dashboard of charts which will have varying widths and also allows a user to change the width. The chart automatically adjusts it's size. What I want is for the legend to appear under that chart but fill the width given. My issue is it seems that the number of columns for the legend is set once and unable to be updated. So if I a chart that covers the entire width of the page I want to be able to show a larger number of columns, but if the chart only has a small amount of width space I would like it to use less columns. I can capture the width and figure out the number of columns I would like but is it possible to redraw the legend dynamically? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide the code you have already.

Comment: The code regarding the legend is:
chartSettings.options = {
   legend: {
    show: true,
    noColumns: 3
   }

I can update the "noColumns" but the legend isn't recreated. If I try the plot.redraw() it does not update the legend table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the plot object returned from `$.plot`, then it's:

```
plot.getOptions().legend.noColumns = 3;
plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/siTbSOihf7w4lKoi9c1F?p=preview).

Comment: Is `plot.draw()` the same as `plot.redraw()` ?

Comment: @Raidri, [according to the api](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods) there is no `redraw` method.